# cannot import name 'HTTPException' from 'urllib3.connection'

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am building an application on AWS Lambda using serverless framework.
And trying to import requests library through requirements.txt.
But, it didn't work. came out "cannot import name 'HTTPException' from 'urllib3.connection'" error message.

I can't understand why it doesn't work.
please help.

**serverless.yml**

```
service: test-app

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-package-external
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: false
    slim: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  stage: dv
  region: ap-northeast-2
  timeout: 10
  memorySize: 128
  stackName: ${self:service}
  variableSyntax: "\\${((?!AWS)[ ~:a-zA-Z0-9._'\",\\-\\/\\(\\)]+?)}"
  profile: test-profile
  role: arn:aws:iam::1234:role/role-test
  environment:
    domainPrefix: 'kic'
    moduleName: 'deptest2'
    phasePrefix: ${self:custom.stage}
    projectPrefix: ‘han’
    regionPrefix: 'an2'
  apiName: api-an2-dv-${self:service}
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-001
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-001
      - subnet-002

functions:
  dep2:
    handler: dep2_handler.dep2_handler
    name: lmd-an2-dv-${self:service}-deptest2
```

**requirements.txt**

```
-i https://pypi.python.org/simple
requests==2.22.0
```

**dep2_handler.py**

```
import requests


def dep2_handler(event, context):
    try:
        print(event)
    except Exception:
        print('fail to handle event data: {}'.format(event))
        return
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the line `-i https://pypi.python.org/simple` in your `requirements.txt`? That line looks out of place. What does it do? Did you try without it? Can you further reduce your code to try and reproduce the problem with a minimal sample? What does your directory structure look like? Does the error occur when you deploy or when you try to run the function? Can you put in a `print("debug")` statement just below the `def dep2_handler...` function header to see if your function is actually started?

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz I removed the line  -i https://pypi.python.org/simple, and it works! thank you!

Comment: Good, I put it as an answer so that this question can be marked as solved / answered.

Comment: I had the same problem, but in my case it was caused by changing the serverless runtime from 3.7 to 3.8. Apparently the cache with the old requests library was still used for 3.8 and raised that error. Deleting serverless cache forced it to download the appropriate python 3.8 requests library

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message was a bit misleading.

As per my comment, there was an offending line in requirements.txt:

The line `-i https://pypi.python.org/simple` needed to be removed.